# Ubuntu 12.04; How to check if vsync is enabled?

Tags: 12.04

When I run `glxgears` I get output like this;

```
9012 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1802.212 FPS
```

I understand those results to mean that vsync is not enabled otherwise I would be getting 60fps, the current refresh rate of my monitor. Is that a correct interpretation of those results? How do I check if vsync is enabled?

```
bensley@htpc-ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
bensley@htpc-ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux htpc-ubuntu 3.2.0-60-generic #91-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 19 03:54:44 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4330 CPU @ 3.50GHz (built in Intel HD4600).
```